# Model that has_many other model more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a **Movie** model, and a **Person** model.

The **Movie** model should have actors, writers and producers groups.

The actors, writers and producers are groups of persons, all from the same **Person** model.

What would be the best way to model this?

Thanks.

EDIT: Each person could be an actor, a writer and a producer at the same time. And they all have the same attributes.

EDIT 2:
What I want to do is something like this:

```
Class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :image, :information, :duration, :director, etc...

  has_many :persons, as: :writers <-- (IDK if this is possible)
  has_many :persons, as: :producers <-- (IDK if this is possible)
  has_many :persons, as: :actors <-- (IDK if this is possible)
end
Class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :birthdate, :birthplace, :height, :information, :name, etc..
end
```

and creating groups in the Movie model, so I can call them like this:

```
@writers = @movie.writers
@actors = @movie.actors
@producers = @movie.producers
```

all made-up by Person objects, persons which could be any of the 3 types.

A Person could be involved in many other movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want different models, why not just add a profession column to your Person (or Movie) model?  Assuming they have pretty much the same attributes, they can all be handled by the same table. You could use multiple: true, to allow to choose multiple professions per person.

P.S. Could you elaborate why you use a separate Movie model for these professions?

**Edit:**

If you have many professions and a person can have multiple professions at the same time, you might consider using a has_many :through relationship. As in:

```
class Person
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :professions, through: assignments
end

class Assignment
  belongs_to :person_id
  belongs_to :profession_id
end

class Profession
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :persons, through: assignments
end
```

This way, you could add additional attributes in the join model if necessary.

Comment: I see. Personally I would like STI in this matter, but a scope for producers etc. could also work perfectly fine if you really don't want multiple models.

Comment: This would be a nice starting point: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how different the attributes are for your actors, writers and producers. If they will all have the same attributes (or mostly the same attributes), you could use single table inheritance. Have one of the attributes in your Person model be an attribute called `type` and this will trigger STI.

The use of STI or not depends on your tolerance for null values in your database. If the number of shared attributes between actors, writers and producers is low, you will end up with a number of null values and it might be better to have a different class for each one.

The official docs are limited on STI but I found a couple of interesting blog posts that go into more detail on implementation:

http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance
http://www.christopherbloom.com/2012/02/01/notes-on-sti-in-rails-3-0/

Answer (score 1):

Given the new information you can do

```
Class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :writers, :class_name => 'Person', :conditions => ['role = "writer"']
  has_many :producers, :class_name => 'Person', :conditions => ['role = "producer"']
  has_many :actors, :class_name => 'Person', :conditions => ['role = "actor"']
end
```

the conditions inside the :conditions will be different depending how you implement the roles assignation.

You have all the information here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: wouldn't having a role column in the Person model prevent a Person from having more than one role?

Answer (score 0):

Use activerecord `:through` option

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

You can use [STI](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance)  - Single Table Inheritance. For this you need to have `type` attribute in your `Person` model which will store the `type` of the `Person`.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Actor < Person
end

class Writer < Person
end

class Producer < Person
end
```

Comment: I didn't want to make a different model for each type of person because they all have the same attributes and a Person could be an actor, a writer and a producer at the same time.

Comment: Then you can add column called `roles` to `Person` which will contain the array(or comma separated values)  of `roles`

Answer (score 0):

Given that all the roles have the same attribute and therefore can use the same class and model. If you want to have multiple roles at the same time your best bet to my understanding is to use an atribute role in the Person model. You can use a has_many association.